# How to prevent modal form from being closed on submit button when form.is_valid() == False?

Tags: python, html, django

I've got a modal form in my template, the form below is validated (date_of_birthday cannot be less than 18 years ago). Is there any way, to not close the form **if not** form.is_valid() and display error messages and close the form if form.is_valid()?

```
       <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <img onclick="" id="close-icon" src="{% static 'icons/cancel.svg' %}">
                            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% for field in profile_form %} 
                                {% if field.name == "date_of_birth" %}
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px 30px;">
                                    {{field.label}}
                                    <div>
                                        {{field}}
                                    </div>
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {{error}}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% elif field.name == 'bio' %}
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px 30px; display: grid;">
                                    {{field.label}}
                                    {{field}}
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {{error}}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% else %}
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10px 30px;">
                                    {{field.label}}
                                    {{field}}
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {{error}}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            <button type="button" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                            
                        
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

View:
def post(self, request, user_id):

```
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        date_of_birth = profile_form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        image = profile_form.cleaned_data['image']
        background_image = profile_form.cleaned_data['background_image']
        bio = profile_form.cleaned_data['bio']
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        userprofile.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        if image is not None:
            userprofile.image = image
        if background_image is not None:
            userprofile.background_image = background_image 
        if bio is not None:
            userprofile.bio = bio 
        userprofile.save()
        return redirect('/profile/{}'.format(user_id))
    ctx = {
        "profile_form": profile_form
    }
    return redirect('/profile/{}'.format(user_id))
```

Does API View would be better in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `else` statement for redirect the user if `form is not valid` like :-

```
from django.contrib import messages

def post(self,request,user_id):
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if profile_form.is_valid():
        date_of_birth = profile_form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        .......
        ............
        return redirect('/profile/{}'.format(user_id))

    else:
        messages.errror(request,'Something went Wrong !')

    ctx = {
        "profile_form": profile_form
    }
    return redirect('/profile/{}'.format(user_id))
```

Comment: When you redirect, doesn't it clear form errors? Besides, i don't have any url to redirect to this form. This is kind of popup window.

Comment: If it is a model then you can `show an error message`  .EDITED MY ANSWER

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that, nevertheless i would like to display error messages in form template. Thanks anyway.